# How to make objects more visible in wireframe mode?

Tags: wireframe

My basic cube looks like this in wireframe mode:

[image]

It's almost invisible. And I saw others' looks dark and thick:

[image]

My viewport shading options are exactly the same as his. I know there is a "random" option to make it more clear, but I don't want random colors everywhere, just darker and visible wireframes.

Comment: Hello :). Didn't you accidentally change the wire color? It's in *Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Wire* (it's third from top)

Comment: @JachymMichal Oh you're right! Now I feel embarrassed lol. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably accidentally changed the wire color.
It can be found in *Preferences > Themes > 3D View > Wire*.

And don't forget to save your preferences :).

[image]